# Disable OneDrive handling in Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, sync, onedrive

Since I use OneDrive, each document I create or edit in Word is handled as an online document, when I save it in the folder structure, OneDrive is syncing.

Documents are handled as "http://d.docs.live.net/..." instead of "C:\MyFolder\mydocument.docx".

I want OneDrive to sync my folders in the cloud (as Dropbox or GoogleDrive do it) but I don't want to takeover OneDrive the default behavior of handling files in Word, Excel etc.

BTW, it seems to slow down the opening and saving of documents in word.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To never store your documents on OneDrive, change the default
to save to the computer by :

In the menu File > Options, click on the left on Save, and in the right pane
untick "Show additional places for saving, even if sign-in may be required" and
tick "Save to Computer by default", finally specify your
"Default local ﬁle location", and click OK.

[image]

For one-time disable of OneDrive, right-click on its 'cloud' icon on the traybar
and choose `Exit`.

To totally disable OneDrive, see the article
[How to Disable & Replace OneDrive in Windows 10](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/disable-replace-onedrive-windows-10/).

For more info, see the article
[Before a Microsoft Office 2013 install, beware of potential gotchas](https://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/tip/Before-a-Microsoft-Office-2013-install-beware-of-potential-gotchas)
(it calls OneDrive by the name of SkyDrive but the rest is still valid).